# How to change ActionBar Item depending on Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I am trying to create a selected and unselected Item on a the ActionBar in my app. For example, when the user is in a fragment if they click the Item in the ActionBar, the ImageView will switch from a grey to a red square and if they switch to a different fragment then come back it will still be selected. So each fragment can either be selected or unselected based upon the color of the square and if the user clicked it or not. I am unsure how to implement this, anything helps?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the location of the item in the `ActionBar`, this can be presented as a fragment option. Each fragment that gets inflated has the chance to inflate its own menu items into the action bar. This can be done by calling `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` in fragment's onCreate or maybe in the constructor. This will cause the `onCreateOptionsMenu` / `onPrepareOptionsMenu` / `onOptionsItemSelected` methods to be called and this gives you the chance to add your menu item which you can control based on your fragment's state.

Answer (score 0):

First off, for saving state in a fragment, you can use `onSaveInstanceState()` to remember your selected state.  You would need a property on your fragment:

```
    private boolean mSelected;
```

In your `onSaveInstanceState()` override you save this value:

```
    outState.putBoolean("selected", mSelected);
```

Then in `onCreate()` you can recover the value:

```
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mSelected = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("selected");
    }
```

And in `onCreateView()` you use the selected property to set up your `ImageView`:

```
    imageView.setBackground(mSelected ? R.color.gray : R.color.red); // for example
```

So now when your user switches away from the fragment then comes back, the `ImageView` will have the same selection state as before.

Next thing is the action bar.  Fragments can make their own changes to the menu.  Start by calling `setHasMenuOptions(true)` in your fragment's `onCreateView()`.  Then you override `onCreateOptionsMenu()` and `onOptionsItemSelected()` just like you would for an activity.